# Create a dictionary from 2 lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to create a dictionary based on the three lists I have:

```
Hier = ['A', 'C']
values = [10, 20]
All = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

The results shall look like this:

```
{"A", 10, "B": "", "C": 20, "D":""}
```

Comment: That's not a legal `dict` at the end there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```py
Hier = ["A", "C"]
values = [10, 20]
All = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

d = dict.fromkeys(All, "")
d.update(zip(Hier, values))
print(d)
```

Prints:

```py
{'A': 10, 'B': '', 'C': 20, 'D': ''}
```

---

EDIT: removed `dict()` from `.update`

Comment: Minor improvement: Drop the temporary `dict` for the `update` call; `update` accepts an iterable of key/value pairs, so it could read from the `zip` iterator directly: `d.update(zip(Hier, values))`